# Android removing category from SettingsActivity without crashing app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created a settings activity using eclipse. The setting activity creates two example categories automatically (in addition to the general settings): Notifications and Data & Sync. The problem is that I simply don't know how to delete them without making my app crash:

I tried simply deleting this block (i converted it to a comment) but the app crashed:

```
    // Add 'notifications' preferences, and a corresponding header.
    fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_notifications);
    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
```

I cannot start from a blank activity since this is my first app, so I would prefer to start from the example settings activity.

How can I delete the "notifications" preference so I only have the general settings and data & sync?

This is the content of the logcat when it crashes:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say from your small example. What does eclipse say when it crashes (switch to the DDMS or DEBUG view and have a look at the logcat output)

If you are just starting, I suggest you use the wizard to create a first application instead of changing an existing example.

Comment: I attached the content of the logcat on the original question. I don't know if it helps.

Comment: You have a nullpointer exception. Can't tell as you didn't supply all of the code but I think you may still be using "fakeheader" after you commented the "new" line out

Comment: thanks, I actually couldn't resolve it but I looked for wizards and ended up following a tutorial and managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if this removes the preference:

```
myPreferenceScreen.remove(notifications);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to do the same and I think I finally found what to do.
First, make sure that you do not delete the declaration of fakeHeader.
Then comment the lines:

```
fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_notifications);
getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
```

If you dont do anything more you'll run into a null pointer exception. The reason is simply that some lines below you will find the method "setupSimplePreferenceScreen". It makes sure that the values the user changes are updated accordingly. To make it work you also have to comment the line:

```
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
```

Be aware though, that this will only make the settings screen work on non XL-large screens!
This is because the code uses two different methods of presenting the settings. The easy one is the one without fragments, which uses the deprecated methods in "setupSimplePreferencesScreen".
Unfortunately running even the unmodified settingsActivity on a device with an XL screen caused in instant crash for me. So you have to figure that out on your own :)

**EDIT:** gian1200 pointed out the steps to do in order to get this working in his comment to this answer.

By the way, to add custom settings have a look at the following files (I am assuming you didnt rename the files)

1:

```
/res/values/strings_activity_settings.xml
```

contains the names and descriptions of the settings

2:

```
/res/xml/pref_data_sync.xml
/res/xml/pref_general.xml
/res/xml/pref_headers.xml
/res/xml/pref_notification.xml
```

These files contain the header names of the settings categories (pref_headers.xml) as well as the category contents. You can easily add new categories or modify existing ones. I think it's best if you play around with them a little. You will easily get the hang of it.

Comment: it is not "buggy"you need to change the pref_headers.xml and put your package name and the name of the activity class that works as Settings

Comment: Thanks a lot for that information I will try that. Wish I could vote up your comment! ;]

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove

```
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
```

if you want to remove the notification section. There are a few other bindPreferenceSummaryToValue()'s that match the other example categories.